# How should I invest my money once I hit 60?

Tags: diablo-iii

Once I hit 60 kill Diablo on Hell and invest all my money in an affordable level 60 equipment, how should I invest my new money?

I have (partly) invested in the following, but everything needs improvement:

- Jeweler
- Blacksmith
- Stash space

There are also the following possibilities:

- Better items, although they start at 100 k each.
- Recipes (Jeweler, Blacksmith)
- Items from Blacksmith
- Better Gems

Basically I know my options but I do not know how to optimally invest my money.

Comment: Don't invest in the blacksmith or gems at the moment, it will be lost wages. The upcomming patch is compeltley changing both of these mechanics in repsect to costs.

Comment: If you're level 60 and want to run Inferno, start planning on investing at least 100-200k in each item, especially your weapon. This obviously doesn't need to be done at once, but get a good weapon, upgrade your worst armor first, and farm up some gold.

Comment: @Emerica: Really!?  Do you have a link?

Comment: @BlueRaja-DannyPflughoeft: The 1.0.3 changes are already listed on bnet which mentions the artisan changes

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As Emerica said in the comments, Crafters are changing in the upcoming patch, (1.0.3) so they are not the best way to invest your money at the moment.

Saving your money up to buy gear on the auction house, while farming for gear.

Farming for gear pre 1.0.3  you will want to spend time in Act 3/4 of Hell, rather than act 1 of Inferno.

Once 1.0.3 comes, you can start farming in Act 1 of Inferno and start getting good gear. As well as acts 2+ being revamped in the future.

A lot of this info is sourced from this post: http://us.battle.net/d3/en/blog/6262208/Patch_103_Design_Preview-6_6_2012#blog

Once the real money auction house goes live (currently projected to be 06/12/12) you can always sell some of your gold for real money if that interests you.

Answer (score 6):

Others will provide more meaningful answers about the best use of your coin to improve your character and amass further wealth, but since you mentioned it, I wanted to say a word about stash space.

I long ago learned that in most video games, **having available inventory space is functionally equivalent to happiness**. Having lots of bag space will save you time on town trips, help you stay organized when buying and selling, let you save all the gear you want for alts, save any sentimental items you may accrue, and more.

So by all means invest in the artisans, the auction house, getting a few razzle-dazzle gems that'll last you for ages. But an investment in at least *some* additional working room in your stash will never be wasted. ;)

Comment: Agreed, was one of the first things I unlocked as well. Don't forget that stash is account bound as well.

Answer (score 1):

Don't bother with leveling the artisans at this time, for progress in Inferno you're going to want a high DPS weapon, lots of health and resistances, and then your primary stat. It would of course help to know which class you're playing but this is a general outline. Spending money on the artisans is expensive and there are better items on the auction house until you find rare recipes.

Comment: A well crafte gam can really help out a socketable item and most hight level gems that don't drop are overpriced (right now you can't even buy any) at the ah som crafting the gems yourself is cost effective at this moment. You don't need rare recipes to craft good items. Crafting items is really a big gamle if you are lucky you can get items worth many millons for around 50k. But usually you have to try and craft many times. So for blacksmithing its usually a question about if you feel lucky.

Comment: Yeah but he said 'invest', I would never recommend gambling as a valid strategy for investment.

Comment: Gambling has a higher risk. To never consider it is stupid. It's just a question of how high a risk your willing to take. A friend of mine got an item he sold for just over 10m from crafting. So net  profit he has earn money from crafting.

Answer (score 1):

Like others have suggested, the artisans can wait. In fact, I would argue that artisans can be put on hold indefinitely. The future nerfs to the costs associated with crafting will probably cause commodity prices to drop further. And gems have diminishing returns, I wouldn't spend any money trying to get the best gem possible yet.

Stash space is an obvious choice, but not as an investment.

Look for incremental and cost efficient items on the auction house. Yes most of them are overpriced; but good deals do exist. Use the max buyout feature of the AH extensively. As soon as you buy better gear, put your current gear on the AH with a reduced price. The ide